# How to use ajax with codeigniter's modules

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter, jquery

I have a page written in codeigniter framework.
Now I want to add a button to page (eg 'show more') that will get data with 'ajax.php' from the database and display them on the site, but I do not want it separately connect to the database and then get the results, just want to be able to collect data (in ajax.php) as well as in codeigniter controllers (using models)...

Hope you understand me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go just add view more button and call this js and ajax function..This is code i have used please see it and use it as per your requirment

```
$('.more').live("click",function() 
    {
        var this_tag = $(this);
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if(ID)
        {
            $("ol#updates").addClass('tiny-loader');
            this_tag.html('Loading.....');
            $.post(siteUrl+"ajax/ajax_more",{lastmsg:ID,restid:$(this_tag).data("restid")},function(html){
            $("ol#updates").removeClass('tiny-loader');
            $("ol#updates").append(html);
            $("#more"+ID).remove();// removing old view-more button

            });
        }
        else
        {
            this_tag.fadeOut('slow');// no results
        }
        return false;
    });
```

code in ajax file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax_more extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('general_model');
        $this->limit =REVIEW_DETAIL;
     }

    public function index($offset = 0)
    {
         $lastmsg=$this->input->post('lastmsg');
         $rest_id=$this->input->post('restid');
        $value=('reviews.*,usermaster.Name as User');
        $joins = array
        (
              array
                (
                  'table' => 'tk_usermaster',
                  'condition' => 'usermaster.Id = reviews.UserId',
                  'jointype' => 'leftouter'
                 ),
        );
        $this->results = $this->general_model->get_joinlist('reviews',$value,$joins,array('reviews.Status'=>'Enable','reviews.RestaurantId'=>$rest_id,'reviews.Id <'=>$lastmsg),'reviews.Id','desc',$this->limit,$offset);
        $data['list_review']= $this->results['results'];
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($data['list_review'] as $row): ?>
         <div class="user_reviews_data" >
                        <div class="width-20 float-left">
                            <span class="padleft-10"><?php echo $row->User; ?> </span>
                            <br/>
                            <span class="padleft-10 "><div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="<?php echo $row->Rating;?>" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true"></div></span>
                           <div class="muted padleft-10 float-left"><small><?php echo date('dS M Y' ,strtotime($row->CreatedDate)); ?></small></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="width-80 float-left"><?php echo $row->Feedback;?></div>
                        <span class="report_span"><a href="<?php echo site_url('report_form/index/review/'.$rest_id.'/'.$row->Id);?>" class="pop-up" data-element_id="<?php echo $row->Id; ?>">Report this Feedback <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>themes/images/FLAG_GREY.png"></a></span>    
                   </div>
        <?php
         $msg_id = $row->Id;
         endforeach; ?>
         </div>
                <div id="more<?php echo @$msg_id; ?>" class="btn-container center_text morebox">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="more btn orange_signup" id="<?php echo @$msg_id; ?>" data-restid="<?php echo $rest_id; ?>" title="view more">View More</a>
                </div>

         <?php
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response! check on Monday and let you know :) p.s. where i should put ajax.php file? in ..\application\controllers ?